# How to use Python plot at the location on the parabola closest to the external point, plot the tangent line and the normal line?

Tags: python, math

The question is here: https://ibb.co/zfFj9kp

How can I write python code to find the shortest distance between the point and parabola?
And how can I plot the tangent line with python?

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate the point `(x2/y2)` on the parabola by minimizing its distance to the external point `(x1/y1)`. See [stackexchange's mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443736/find-a-point-on-a-parabola-thats-closest-to-another-point) for a nice approach. The roots of the resulting cubic polynomial can be identified with [numpy's roots](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html).

To draw the tangent, first identify the slope from the distant point to the closest point on the parabolar, e.g. via `m1 = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`. Then, calculate the [perpendicular slope](https://www.cuemath.com/geometry/slope-of-perpendicular-lines/) via `m2 = -1/m1`.

Lastly, create a linear equation from the calculated closest point and the perpendicular slope, i.e. calulate the y-offset `b = y2-m2*x2` and draw the respective linear equation `y2 = m2*x2 + b`, e.g. with [matplotlib's pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html).